# Structure of Schema in Firebase

Tags: firebase

I have a strong background in relational databases. However, I'm always looking to improve my skills. Recently, I've been exposed to Firebase. It seems pretty interesting. However, I'm slightly confused by the "schema" if that's even the correct term.

From what I can tell, each Firebase "app" basically represents a single "table". Thus, if I am building a web application that has two related, but seperate entities, I would have to have two firebase "apps". For example, perhaps I am building a web application that has football teams, coaches and players. In a relational database, I may have something like this:

**Relational Database**

```
Team       Coach       TeamCoachLookup   Player      TeamPlayerLookup
----       -----       ---------------   ------      ----------------
ID         ID          ID                ID          ID
Name       FirstName   TeamID            FirstName   TeamID
Location   LastName    CoachID           LastName    PlayerID
```

The above shows a possible relational database structure. Some may want to have a `Person` table with a `RoleID` to represent whether the person is a Player or a Coach. That's one approach. Still, when I look at the Firebase model, I have trouble getting my head around how the above would be structured. Would it be:

http://teams.firebaseio.com
http://coaches.firebaseio.com
http://players.firebaseio.com

Where the JSON of each item would represent a row in the database? Or, should it just be `http://teams.firebaseio.com` and the schema would look like this:

```
{
  coaches: [
    { id:1, firstName:'Joe', lastName:'Smith' }
  ],
  players: [
    { id:1, firstName:'Bill', lastName:'Mans' },
    { id:2, firstName:'Zack', lastName:'Dude' }
  ]
}
```

The second approach seems to make more sense to me. However, I do not see how Firebase supports that. Instead, in my mind, it looks like Firebase has one URL for each "table" and the JSON isn't really hierarchical. Am I way off? Is there any documentation that anyone can recommend to me?

Thanks!

Comment: https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The corresponding concepts should be (Firebase <=> relational):

- application <=> schema
- root node <=> table
- child node <=> row
- node key <=> row id (typically [push ids](https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/saving-data.html#section-push))

In your concrete example:

- football-app.firebaseio.com

  - teams

    - fx7Q7q

      - name: "Foo"
  - coaches

    - ix0GWF

      - firstName: "Joe"
      - lastName: "Smith"
  - players

    - uQ8fJK

      - firstName: "Bill"
      - lastName: "Mans"
  - teamCoachLookup

    - QkW9uH

      - team: "fx7Q7q"
      - coach: "ix0GWF"
  - teamPlayerLookup

    - BmI48N

      - team: "fx7Q7q"
      - player: "uQ8fJK"

See also https://www.firebase.com/docs/web/guide/structuring-data.html.

Comment: Great answer. One thing I'd consider is to store the team/coach and team/player lookups under each team/coach/player too. It would duplicate some data, but you'd have to read fewer locations. If you leave the 5 tables separate, I'd go for `/teamCoachLookup/$teamId/$coachId` and `/teamPlayerLookup/$teamId/$playerId`. This will prevent having to query to get all players for a team; instead you can use direct access: `ref.child('teamPlayerLookup').child(teamId).on('value'...`